# How to forbid creation run configuration in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Each time I press run button (or using shortcut for it), eclipse creates run configuration in some unpredictable way (looks like it uses currently selected file in PyDev Package Explorer, which is very strange). How to force eclipse to use only manually created run configurations and forbid to creating new one for the current project. I have 'Always launch the previously launched application' checked, but it doesn't help.